# Where can I have html tags in a database format?

Tags: html, css, sql-server

I need to have a database filled with HTML tags and attributes, 
Meaning, the data inside the tables is just html tags, the description, and attributes.

I also need to have the same for CSS.

Is there a possibility to find a download for such data set? either in sql format, csv, excel, access file...etc that can be imported into MSSQL.

Where can find it? or should I create it from a reference?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please elaborate on what exactly do you want to store? Why would you want to store HTML tags on a database?

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible idea. I'd strongly suggest you consider not doing this before you go down a path that could cause you an enormous amount of pain later on.

Comment: I'm trying to develop a web application as a part of my final certificate project. the objective is to create an interface where user can select html tags and insert it into a work area then preview the result. just like wysiwyg apps.

Comment: @scsimon . may be you're right, but what is other alternatives for completing my project? it's supposed to be just like wysiwyg apps. any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

Comment: So how was the visual html designer was developed?